# Word choice about occupation

Tags: vocabulary

When I’d like to generally talk about people who are doing their jobs
at schools, coffee shops, or supermarkets, can I refer him/her or them
as a worker, workers?

For example

At a coffee shop:

> “I think that tall worker is really cute.”

At Asda:

> “If you don’t know where the toilet roll is, I’ll ask another worker.”

I’m an EFL learner and I really don’t know all English vocabulary about occupations.

So, I’d like to know if it’s wrong to refer a server as a worker (in
case that I don't know the specific word to use.)

Comment: I believe *employee* might be a better choice in the given examples (at least the 2nd one - I don't really understand the 1st one).

Comment: You could also say 'member of staff' or, in a shop, 'assistant' (in British English). 'Worker' is more appropriate to factory employees.

Comment: @KateBunting That's what I was thinking.

Comment: "Member of staff" is a bit formal (and hence inappropriate) for the first example sentence, but not the second one... it's perfectly fine for the second one. The difference is probably the capacity in which you are referring to them. In the first sentence, their employment is entirely incidental to their attractiveness and the register one might use to describe it. In the second, their employment is entirely relevant. In Japanese, for instance, there is a very general word, 店員 (shop-member); there is no direct equivalent in BrE and 'clerk' might be as best as you can do in AmE.

Answer (score 1):

There are specific and different legal definitions of “worker” and “employee” in the U.K.
In casual usage the word “employee” would be used fairly accurately to its legal meaning, but the word “worker” is not generally used with its legal meaning.

However, in common usage in the U.K. we’d use a more specific term for the type of role (barista, cashier, etc).
In casual conversation “employee” would seem a bit formal, as it emphasises their employment status. 
“worker” in casual usage might suggest manual/physical work.
“Staff member” or “member of staff” is free of connotations, and is probably the safest to use if you don’t know someone’s job title.

Comment: Thank you very much Dan. Your answer is what I was looking for. : )

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that some terms for a person who works have become loaded. So, once upon a time, you could generally use the term 'servant' to describe some worker in a non-specific occupation. Obviously that word is no longer appropriate.  That person's big boss, the Chief Executive or whatever, might well have taken to referring to all of their employees as 'colleagues', but that expression is no help if you are not a member of the organisation in question. In BrE 'assistant', as suggested by @KateBunting, might work, but even that is beginning to sound a bit condescending. One hears 'agent', but in BrE that word carries some very specific connotations that may well not be appropriate in every case. "Worker" might be OK but it suggests that there are other people around who do not work.

So, in short, the OP has put her finger on a real problem. I doubt there is a single term. The person you fancy in the coffee shop might be the barista, and the person in Asda who might know where the toilet roll is might be "one of your colleagues."

Comment: Thank you very much. In my country, we do have a general term for calling people working in restaurants, coffee shops, or universities. And that word is not offensive. But in UK, language and culture are different. That’s why I’m always well aware of my words. Thank you again Jeremy!

Comment: @RoseCarter That's interesting. Does your general term covers everyone who works in what we would call "customer facing" or "public facing" roles; that is that their work is mainly dealing with customers? I must congratulate you on the quality of your written English by the way.